# dropdown without select statement - able to click on the values, but values not set

Tags: python, selenium

I was trying to select multiple values from a dropdown which dont have "Select" tag. With the below code, im trying to select 2 values(Upsell, Price Increase) from the dropdown and im successful in clicking on that. But the issue is values are not selected and its just highlighted [image: Values are highlighted but not set] and the control is not going to another object, say the GO button mentioned in the page. Please see the attachment, expecting the values to be this way [image: Expecting the values to be this way after clicking]

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'select-cBooking_Type_NL_CS_US')]").click()
OppType=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='menu-Booking_Type_NL_CS_US']/div[3]/ul/li")
for e in OppType:
   if e.text == 'Upsell' or e.text == 'Price Increase':
        e.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'GO')]").click()
```

Comment: Please provide URL.

Comment: its an internal application

Comment: Is it possible to share a sample code to select multiple values from a dropdown list. Please note that developers havent used select tag for dropdown lost. The above code works for a dropdown box which can select single values(where multiselect is not possible)